# Send file in chunks of 10kb byte array C# over HTTP

Tags: c#, http, filestream

I have a client that can only hold 10kb into memory. I have a file which is 70KB that the client is downloading. Problem is when client try to download the complete file over http request it throw memory exception.

What I wanted to do is that when a client send http request to downloads a file, I intercept the request on server, break the files into chunks of byte array of 10KB and write in the response stream. Client than reads the stream one by one and write it directly on file system instead of its own memory.

I tried to implement it but still no luck. Is there any way I can achieve it?

My Handler:

```
 public class FileDownloadHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
      
        #region IHttpHandler Members

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            // Return false in case your Managed Handler cannot be reused for another request.
            // Usually this would be false in case you have some state information preserved per request.
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var fileExtension = GettingExtension(context.Request.RawUrl);
            if (!fileExtension.Equals(".bin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                context.Response.Write("Invalid extension");
                context.Response.Flush();
                return;
            }

            //reading dummy file from server
            string fileName = @"C:\FileHandler\File\AA_GS_BUILD.bin"; 
            byte[] arr = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.ContentType = ".bin";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");

            // create list of bytes array of 10000 size of each byte array
            foreach (byte[] copySlice in arr.Slices(10000))
            {
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(copySlice);
            }
            context.Response.Flush();
        }
        public string GettingExtension(string rawUrl)
        {
            return rawUrl.Substring(rawUrl.LastIndexOf(".", System.StringComparison.Ordinal));
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can fix this client problem by changing your server. It's the client that must stream the response carefully.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I realise that I misread the question. For some reason I thought it said the server had this limitation. Re-reading it, I agree with your summary of the situation. The client needs to control how much data it receives at once.

Comment: Probably would be better to add support for standard RANGE header instead hacking up some custom protocol. Some example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vendettamit/handling-range-specific-content-request-in-webapi-Asp-Net/